# Android NDK Cross Compile FFmpeg, dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, cross-compiling, android-ffmpeg

Android NDK-r20 cross compile FFmpeg4.2 success, but my app crash with

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol
>   __aeabi_idiv

#### This is the ffmpeg4.2 source code with my "build_android.sh"

[ffmpeg-android-build](https://github.com/binglingziyu/ffmpeg-android-build)

```
config the NDK r20 root path in "build_android.sh"
$ cd ffmpeg-android-build
$ ./build_android.sh
$ make -j 4
$ make install
```

#### This is my android project to test the ffmpeg

[ffmpeg-android-test](https://github.com/binglingziyu/ffmpeg-android-test)

#### Seemed the solution，don't know how to do in my situation

[#cannot-locate-symbols](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#cannot-locate-symbols)

#### Excepted

1. NDK-r20 and FFmpeg-4.2 is needed (cant change the version)
2. My android test project run

Answer (score 0):

Now,problem seems to have been solved.

[Old build_android.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/binglingziyu/ffmpeg-android-build/8bb12dcbfc438ef55d015e8b8266262f1ec5d3e8/build_android.sh)

[New build_android.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/binglingziyu/ffmpeg-android-build/master/build_android.sh)